# Eek! Where did the stylesheets go?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Since half an hour or so, Meta SO (not reproducable on other SE sites) seem to have lost their header and footer part, i.e. all sites are rendered as

```
<div id="mainbar" class="ask-mainbar">
```

being the first line of `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`. This applies to all pages.

Is that just me?

Comment: No idea what that was but it is fixed now.

Comment: That was really weird.

Comment: Those are back now!

Comment: Because we like to browse like a googlebot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just created this, couldn't resist..

[image]

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooo! Too much fun on meta!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: **+1** for reference to caching.

Comment: @Oded I think you missed an exclamation mark out...

Comment: Sorry @Oded; while your answer is technically correct, and this is technically not even an answer, I'll still have to accept this as the *correct answer*!

Answer (score 8):

Something went wonky on the latest build - we are looking into it.

For some reason the master page template didn't render.

Comment: Good thing I remembered the URL to the questions page; you probably would never have found out about this bug if I didn't ask this question ;-)

Comment: @nijansen - Yeah, it isn't like I am on Meta all day long. Oh... wait.